# Objective-C bridging header file not found

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bridging-header

I have a class name `AppState` which is using a swift class object

```
#import "Sonic-Swift.h"

@interface AppState : NSObject
@property (class) NSMutableArray<"Swift class" *> *entity;
```

Now I need to use this class (`AppState`) in the swift file. So I'm trying to import this class in the bridging header.

But after importing this file the app gives an error on the "#import "Sonic-Swift.h"" line "File not found".

```
failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/krishna_mac_2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Apps-gqelclyzwvyomhcchmjjsejrznaw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Sonic-Bridging-Header-swift_3RJ3MQEOEFTPD-clang_26Q2UBYWMY12Y.pch' for bridging header '/Users/krishna_mac_2/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Github/Sonic/iOS/Sonic/Sonic-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: #import "Sonic-Swift.h" it should be in **.m** file and one more thing you don't need that header file unless you are using swift classes in your AppState class

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I am creating swift file object in AppState.h class that why I need to import that.

Comment: Then try `@class MySwiftClass;`   don't add header file in .h

Comment: thanks, let  me try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import "Sonic-Swift.h"
```

should be in `.m` file only.

If you want to use Swift class in `.h` file then you should use

```
@class MySwiftClass;
```