# Failed to emit precompiled header because Loop condition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

Let said I have Swift and Objc classes, and a MyProject-Bridging.h

BazSwiftClass.swift

```
public class BazSwiftClass: NSObject {
    public let foo: String
    @objc init(foo: String) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}
```

FooClass.h

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
@interface FooClass : NSObject {
     - (BazSwiftClass)bazMethod;
}
```

I want to access the `FooClass.h` in another Swift Class (let said BarSwiftClass)

```
public class BarSwiftClass {
     public hello() -> BazSwiftClass {
          return FooClass().bazMethod()
     } 
}
```

I need FooClass.h in my swift file, so I added FooClass in my MyProject-Bridging.h

```
#import "FooClass.h"
```

So the Flow is like **BarSwiftClass -> FooClass -> BazSwiftClass**

It can't work because the compiler show "failed to emit precompiled header" and I think it is because of `#import "FooClass.h"` in MyProejct-Bridging.h

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to import only .h files in bridging header and not .m files so remove reference to .m file clean and rebuild

Comment: I have import only in .h file, but it still causing the error. I edit my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Did you check this link @JeffersonSetiawan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293028/xcode-9-failed-to-emit-precompiled-header

Comment: Yes, I know the problem from that link (I use bridging and in the MyProject-bridging, I import that objc file too), but I want to know can I keep using this method?

Comment: `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` Should be in **.m** File will solve your issue

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507433/objective-c-bridging-header-file-not-found/50508804#50508804

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya if I didn't import in the .h file, I got error  in this `- (BazSwiftClass)bazMethod;`, it showed BazSwiftClass is not a type.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your code

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
@interface FooClass : NSObject {
     - (BazSwiftClass)bazMethod;
}
```

With

```
@class BazSwiftClass
@interface FooClass : NSObject {
     - (BazSwiftClass)bazMethod;
}
```

and in **FooClass.m** File  you can import    **#import "MyProject-Swift.h"**

Comment: Thank you @PrashantTukadiya !! After use (@)class BazSwiftClass I can make it compiled.

Comment: In general import as few things as possible in your `.h` files and try to use only forward class and protocol references.

Comment: In general import as few things as possible in your `.h` files and try to use only forward class and protocol references.